Chainlink VRFv2Consumer deployment error
I am trying to deploy VRFv2Consumer.sol on Sepolia following the guideline of the chainlink documentation.
When I try to deploy the contract via Remix, I receive the following error
creation of VRFv2Consumer errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: value out-of-bounds (argument=null, value="8175068993726590174873866284802336976137448002215161102176666199107832532103")
My interpretation of this, is that my subscription ID is a too large number. This suspicion is confirmed when i enter a lower subscription ID, e.g. 123. it works.
Deploying the contract by other means, e.g. manually through a script, doesnt work, because the subscription ID cant be converted (explicitly and implicitly) to uint64. Changing the variable into uint256 results in other unit mismatches.
Any ideas?
thx
J

The subscription id that you’re getting when creating the subscription using the VRF Subscription Manager is of VRF V2.5, not VRF V2.
Therefore, it’s in uint256 format, instead of uint64, as VRF V2.5 generates and supports the subscription ids in uint256 format whereas VRF V2 generates and supports the subscription ids in uint64 format.
It’s also mentioned in the SUBSCRIPTION MANAGER info box in the doc:

The VRF Subscription Manager is available
to help you create and manage VRF subscriptions. You can create and
manage new V2.5 subscriptions, and manage existing V2 subscriptions,
but you can no longer create new V2 subscriptions in the VRF
Subscription Manager. Alternatively, you can create and manage V2
subscriptions
programmatically.

So, now you can do either of these two things:

Migrate your contract to use VRF V2.5, then it’ll support the longer subscription ids.
Or, you can create the VRF V2 subscription by calling the createSubscription function of the VRF Coordinator contract.

For the latter, you can get the contract address of the VRF Coordinator from the Supported Networks page of VRF V2.
By clicking on the address, it’ll open the VRF Coordinator contract in the corresponding network’s block explorer. Now, you can call the createSubscription function by connecting your wallet.
Like, in case of Eth-Sepolia, you’ll be calling the createSubscription available on this permalink.
After executing the createSubscription successfully (i.e., when the corresponding transaction gets confirmed), you’ll get your newly generated subscription id (i.e., in uint64 format) on the VRF Subscription Manager page. Now, you can fund your corresponding subscription and add your contract as a consumer to it.

The subscription ID is a uint256 now. You should use VRF V2.5 as it takes a uint256 as an input instead of a uint64 which is the cause of the error.
